# How to get a children count in an table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL how can I get the number of children count for any parent in a table

Example

```
Tag       ChildCnt
--------------
1          3 
1.1        0
1.2        1
1.2.1      0
2          2
2.1        0    
2.2        0
```

Comment: Can you show us some SQL statements that you tried to write for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the fastest one:

```
select tag, 
       (select count(*) from some_table t2 where t2.tag like t1.tag||'%' and t2.tag <> t1.tag) as child_count
from some_table t1
order by tag;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b818d/1